# Is it acceptable to connect with clients and colleagues in partner companies on LinkedIn?

Tags: job-change, linkedin, secrecy

If you for instance are planning to change jobs, but have not yet divulged this intent to anyone within your company, is it acceptable to connect with clients and colleagues in partner companies in business-oriented social/professional networks (e.g. LinkedIn)?

Assumptions:

- As a result of your increased activity, your clients and colleagues would be able to figure out that you were planning to change jobs *before your home company*.
- You are not connected to anyone within your home company, so *they would be oblivious to your activity on LinkedIn*.

The intent of connecting would be to expand one's network and hopefully get skills endorsed, and perhaps a few favorable reviews. The intent is *not* in any way to get a job with clients or partners.

---

This question is not a duplicate of the linked question ["Do managers monitor employees' LinkedIn connection activity?"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20250/do-managers-monitor-employees-linkedin-connection-activity), as it asks about connecting with recruiters, whereas this question is asking about connecting with colleagues and clients.

This question is also not a question whether or not the home company would realize any intents to change jobs. It is *assumed* that they will.

Comment: What are you doing to "connect" with your clients and partners that then conveys the intent to change jobs?  Can't you connect with the same people without giving off this intent?  I connect with tons of people and nobody ever accuses me of looking for work... what are you doing?

Comment: I didn't give the -1, but this question is highly subjective and vague.

Comment: @Nelson thank you for the feedback (I don't mind the downvote, I'm just here for an answer). I think it would be obvious to clients and partners who I connect with, as I'm essentially polishing my resume; something that has no obvious benefit besides helping me get a new job. It is also very sudden; I have been in contact with the clients and partners in question for months and years, but never connected with them through these networking sites before.

Comment: What exactly are you doing?  Giving out your resume to your clients and partners?  That's clearly a problem because you'll be trying to get jobs with them.  You then say that you're not doing that, so what **are** you doing?  Connecting with people is very simple.  You go "Hi, I know you from XYZ.  Can I connect with you?"  and people click "Yes" or ignore you... and that's it.  Your fears do not make sense, or you're not really telling people what you are doing.  I'm hoping you're not asking your clients and partners to proofread your resume... there're better people for that.

Comment: @Nelson you are correct in understanding what I am doing (simply connecting). It is what people (inevitably) will read into it that I am worried about. What is connecting with people, if not indirectly generating more exposure to and improving the look and validity of your resume? The profile essentially is a resume, isn't it? I am trying to make it look better so that I can present it to unrelated third-party employers. If you are of the opinion that I am worrying for nothing, then I believe that is a valid answer.

Comment: You are **seriously** and **massively** overthinking.  Look at all your linked in friends and look at all their activities.  How many of them looks like they're looking for jobs with their activity?  How many are not?  If you can't tell, then you need to re-work your perception.  I'm also not going to put up an answer because, at this point, it is entirely a subjective and personal answer, which doesn't fit here.

Comment: @AdamJensen I would not put much faith in "Skill endorsements" on LinkedIn to increase your marketing value. They are basically equivalent to "interests" on other social media sites. To improve your resume look into things like professional editing. The fact that you are currently working also helps; presumably this fact adds at least one item to your resume since last time you used it.

Comment: @Nelson It's a new account, so I have no way of properly gauging friends' activity. Nonetheless, the functionality I've seen essentially all boils down to improving the look of and exposing your resume. *I already have channels of communication with the people in question.* What I don't have is for a way for them to publicly endorse my skills and write publicly visible recommendations for me. Why would I want that (all of a sudden) if I wasn't planning to make a move?

Comment: see also  [What's a subtle and non-desperate way of saying that I'm looking for a new job on LinkedIn?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/35914/whats-a-subtle-and-non-desperate-way-of-saying-that-im-looking-for-a-new-job-o)

Comment: @gnat very helpful questions for me (and they both seem to be telling me completely different things than what I am being told in these comments/answers), but I don't think neither is a duplicate. One is asking about advertising that one is looking for a new job and the other is asking about actively connecting with recruiters.

Comment: What's the core question? That bolded sentence isn't telling me anything.

Comment: @Lilienthal the core question is the first paragraph. I made that one sentence bold because I received a now deleted answer that apparently missed that part. I guess it doesn't particularly help to have it bold either.

Comment: @AdamJensen That seems like a pretty exact duplicate of the linked question though, despite your claim that you're connecting to a different "type" of person. In the end you want to know if suddenly connecting with a lot of people is going to be noticed by your employer. While we can't know for sure, the general answer is given by brwngrldev's answer on the linked question: yes they can notice, yes they can put two and two together.

Comment: @Lilienthal I thought it was clear from my question that I was fully under the impression that people would notice. The question was whether it was acceptable to do something like that. E.g. I'm letting people outside my company, but directly related to my company put two and two together before my company.

Comment: @AdamJensen That's difficult to answer as you'd need to define what "acceptable" means. Is it unprofessional to connect to people you work with on LinkedIn? Of course not, everyone does it all the time. But is that what you mean by connecting? Asking for reviews or endorsements or whatever it is LinkedIn calls it now is never okay in my book but some people don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: @Lilienthal you helped me narrow down what it is I actually want to ask; I actually don't care about LinkedIn specifically; see: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/77041/34128

Comment: @AdamJensen A bit of a wordy title but looks like a good question. If you've resubmitted  and no longer need or want to salvage this question you can opt to [delete it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) (and recover lost reputation to downvotes in the process).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with connecting socially with people outside your company. There may be a potential conflict of interest in some cases further down the track, but that still doesn't stop you socialising.

One thing I am very careful about in such situations is never to say anything bad about my work or workplace. This can backfire badly and I've seen people get sacked, anything you put online is potentially accessible by anyone.

It can also work both ways, people who you have connected with might decide it's a conflict of interest on their behalf if they back you when you apply for a job. I certainly would. Just because I have a contact online doesn't mean I'd endorse them, and it may well mean I don't want them any closer than my computer monitor.